# Share multiple image in FBSDKShare Dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Integrated FBSDKShare for sharing images. I can share only a single image but I want to share multiple images

the code I'm using

```
    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];

    for( int i = 0; i < (int)pActiveSession.aShotImages.count; i++ )
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pActiveSession.aShotImages[i]];
        [pActiveSession.allShotImages addObject:[self resizeImage:image]];

    }
    content.photos = pActiveSession.allShotImages;
    photo.userGenerated = YES;
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:nil];
```

the error I'm getting

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got the solution

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];

        for( int i = 0; i < (int)pActiveSession.aShotImages.count; i++ )
        {
            FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pActiveSession.aShotImages[i]];
            photo.image = image;
            [pActiveSession.allShotImages addObject:photo];

        }
         content.photos = pActiveSession.allShotImages;
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = image;
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
  ...
}
```

As per Facebook integration documentation people need the native Facebook for iOS app installed, version 7.0 or higher